# How can we handle props complication in react functional components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, destructuring, react-functional-component

Lets say that we have a functional component that receives over 15/20 props and contains about 15/20 functions inside its body that work with these props. Some of these props will be used in a few of these functions but other props will only be used in 1/3 functions.

Visual example:

```
const TheComponent(props) => {

    // Functions that use the same props
    const function1 () {
        const {prop1, prop2} = props;
        // do something with props
    }

    const function2 () {
        const {prop1, prop2, prop3} = props;
        // do something with props
    }

    // Functions that do not use the same props
    const function18 () {
        const {prop1, prop5, prop11, prop12, prop19} = props;
        // do something with props
    }

    const function19 () {
        const {prop3, prop10, prop15, prop17} = props;
        // do something with props
    }

    const function20 () {
        const {prop10, prop15} = props;
        // do something with props
    }
}
```

Possible refactor I'm thinking of:

```
const TheComponent({prop1, prop2, prop3, [continues like this all the way to...], prop20}) => {
    // same code
}
```

Possible problems with this:

1. You will have over 15 destructured values inside the functional components parenthesis, is this ok? It seemed messy so I was wondering if its ok to do the destructure inside of the components body instead? E.g. `const {prop1, prop2, prop3, [continues like this all the way to...], prop20} = props;`
2. If that's ok, then won't it be bad because you extract all of the data there and maybe some of the functions will never get called (because lets assume they are called based on different conditions), and as such you won't be using this data? If you destructure it inside of the function though, the destructure happens only once the function is called, and might be a little better memory wise? I'm not sure if it actually has any impact though, we need someone who understands this better than me here to provide an answer as I might be completely wrong.
3. There are cases where data will be destructured from the already destructured data, e.g. `const {somethingFromProp1} = prop1`, if its ok to destructure data from `props` inside the body of the functional component, is it ok to further destructure data from that data inside the body of the functional component after?

So what I'm trying to understand is what would be a optimal way of doing these things?
Because for my first example I really don't like the fact that each function that is created inside of the functional components body will be polluted with different assignments, I feel like we could have a cleaner approach?

Searching for answers for these questions online seems to point to the fact that we should just destructure everything we need, including nested destructured inside of the functional components parenthesis.

Please let me know if there is any additional info I can provide to help.

Comment: You need not worry about the memory and performance when destructuring. Your code will be transpiled anyways, so it won't make a difference. The only issue here seems to me to be the readability and convenience for the developers. I would suggest destructuring the props once inside the function component's body and then using them in your functions.

Comment: Hello @giotskhada, yes you are exactly right, that's precisely what I want to know, the most readable, convenient and usable form of such a scenario! Its good to know that performance won't be an issue here because I've found conflicting answers in a few places, but to be honestly nobody seems to have accounted for the transpiling and needer have I! Thank you very much for opening my eye's to this!

Comment: @giotskhada If nobody comes along with a better answer or any sort of contradictions to what you've said, I think you pretty much covered it with 1. no memory problems, 2. its fine to extract from props inside to body of the functional component. So you should try to post an answer after some time, maybe with 1 or 2 sources or something and I'll accept it.